# Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line, reason: 'no start line', code: 'ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE'

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const rsaWrapper = require('./rsa-wrapper');
// generate opened and closed keys for browser and server
rsaWrapper.generate('server');
rsaWrapper.generate('client');
console.log('Keys generated …');
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Encryption/decryption RSA/AES</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-container">
      <h2>Server public key</h2>
      <textarea id="server_public"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">
      <h2>Client public key</h2>
      <textarea id="client_public"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">
      <h2>Client private key</h2>
      <textarea id="client_private"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="log-container">
    <h1>Log container</h1>
    <div id="log" style="padding-top: 20px"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script> <script>
    var socket = io();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

i am getting error, please help me

[image: 1]

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const rsaWrapper = require("./components/rsa-wrapper");
rsaWrapper.initLoadServerKeys(__dirname);
rsaWrapper.serverExampleEncrypt();

const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

// middleware for static processing
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static"));
// web socket connection event
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("connection");
});
http.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("listening on *:3000");
});
```

```js
const path = require("path");
const rsaWrapper = {};
const fs = require("fs");
const NodeRSA = require("node-rsa");
const crypto = require("crypto");
// open and closed keys generation method
rsaWrapper.generate = (direction) => {
  let key = new NodeRSA();
  // 2048 — key length, 65537 open exponent
  key.generateKeyPair(2048, 65537);
  //save keys as pem line in pkcs8
  fs.writeFileSync(
    path.resolve(__dirname, "../keys", direction + ".private.pem"),
    key.exportKey("pkcs8-private-pem")
  );
  fs.writeFileSync(
    path.resolve(__dirname, "../keys", direction + ".public.pem"),
    key.exportKey("pkcs8-public-pem")
  );
  return true;
};
// encrypting RSA, using padding OAEP, with nodejs crypto:
rsaWrapper.encrypt = (publicKey, message) => {
  let enc = crypto.publicEncrypt({
      key: publicKey,
      padding: crypto.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
    },
    Buffer.from(message)
  );
  return enc.toString("base64");
};
// descrypting RSA, using padding OAEP, with nodejs crypto:
rsaWrapper.decrypt = (privateKey, message) => {
  let enc = crypto.privateDecrypt({
      key: privateKey,
      padding: crypto.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
    },
    Buffer.from(message, "base64")
  );
  return enc.toString();
};
// Loading RSA keys from files to variables:
rsaWrapper.initLoadServerKeys = (basePath) => {
  rsaWrapper.serverPub = fs.readFileSync(
    path.resolve(basePath, "keys", "server.public.pem")
  );
  rsaWrapper.serverPrivate = fs.readFileSync(
    path.resolve(basePath, "keys", "server.private.pem")
  );
  rsaWrapper.clientPub = fs.readFileSync(
    path.resolve(basePath, "keys", "client.public.pem")
  );
};
// Run RSA encryption test scenario. Message is encrypted, log on console in base64 format and message is decrypted and log on console.
rsaWrapper.serverExampleEncrypt = () => {
  console.log("Server public encrypting");
  let enc = rsaWrapper.encrypt(rsaWrapper.serverPub, "Server init hello");
  console.log("Server private encrypting …");
  console.log("Encrypted RSA string ", "\n", enc);
  let dec = rsaWrapper.decrypt(rsaWrapper.serverPrivate, enc);
  console.log("Decrypted RSA string …");
  console.log(dec);
};
module.exports = rsaWrapper;
```

```
Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
at Object.rsaWrapper.encrypt (E:\Web Site\NodeJS\Back end website\encryption\components\rsa-wrapper.js:24:20)
at Object.rsaWrapper.serverExampleEncrypt (E:\Web Site\NodeJS\Back end website\encryption\components\rsa-wrapper.js:59:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Web Site\NodeJS\Back end website\encryption\index.js:5:12)
```

Comment: I'm not so familiar with node.js but it looks to me that in your "rsaWrapper.serverExampleEncrypt" you don't **load** the generated server public key to "rsaWrapper.serverPub" (that may cause the error "PEM routines:get_name:no start line" as the var is empty) ?

Comment: In `rsaWrapper.encrypt` / `.decrypt` the keys are expected as PEM. So you should also check if they are really provided in this format (assuming the are loaded at all), especially including header and footer (with regard to the error message).